# Chrome extension on click and on page load

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to have a chrome extension run on page load as well as on click?

If the user is on a certain page I want the extension to run and append a script to the head of the page that has been loaded.

I then want the user to have the ability to click on the extension and the extension runs a different script that calls the script on the page.

I have seen the following for on page load:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.active) {

    // run script/code here

  }
})
```

and I have been using the following for on click:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf(".mydomain.com/") != -1) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            "file": "contentscript.js"
        }, function () {
            console.log("Script Executed...");
        });
    } else {
        var wrongTab = chrome.i18n.getMessage("wrongTab");
        alert(wrongTab);
    }
});
```

But I want to merge them together as appending a script to the page seems to not always load correctly :/

Answer (score 0):

For always loading on a certain page you should use [manifest-injected scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration), e.g.

```
  "content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches" : ["*://*.mydomain.com/*"],
      "js" : ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
```

This will automatically apply to any page on the matching URL on (re)load.

I didn't quite get when you want to inject a script on click (only on the pages on the same domain as the first script?). If you want to signal an existing content script to do something, the best way to do so is with [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging):

```
// contentscript.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
  if(message.doSomething){
    /* do something with message.data */
  }
});

// background.js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
    tab.id,
    {doSomething: true, data: "anything"},
    function(response) {
      if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        // There was no script listening
      }
    }
  );
});
```

If you want to do something in any page, not only ones you injected to, on button click - then you have to use `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. If you want the button to only be active on certain pages, consider using a [Page Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) instead.

Also, take note of the required permissions. If you want to operate on a tab in the click handler, [`"activeTab"` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) is a good thing.